# Face Exercises - Facial Yoga, Pilates, Etc - Does It Work?

Tags: face, aging, wrinkles, yoga

I would like to get some feedback on anybody that has some insight and/or experience in this area.

I am thinking of purchasing some books on Facial Exercise - 'Facial Yoga' to be precise. Essentially to try and re-shape/contour my face area. Manage my ageing process ... gracefully.

Am I throwing my money down the drain?

Thanks ;)